# When an object gets stored in memory, does the value only get stored or does it get stored as an object?

Tags: javascript

When a value gets stored in the memory, I understand that the value itself gets stored in memory but when it comes to objects, how does it get stored in memory?

Comment: In the end, everything is just a collection of bits and bytes. Can you be more specific about what you want to know?

Comment: While it's an article about performance, this does cover some of the details of how browsers store objects at the C++ code level, if that's any help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/The_performance_hazards_of__%5B%5BPrototype%5D%5D_mutation

Comment: I'm inclined to close this as unclear or too broad, as it's currently written. The phrasing of the question doesn't seem to indicate that the OP even knows what they're trying to ask.

Comment: Objects are actually stored in little colored post-it notes on the refrigerator door. Seriously, an object **IS** a value. Why do you want to know this? Just curiosity? The precise answer is likely to be engine dependent. If you really want to understand this better, you could simply examine the engine source code.

Comment: @torazaburo Oh, so an object is a value just like a number or a string is and gets stored into memory, correct?

Comment: Yes, if that is all you were asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gives a good idea on how objects are stored in memory:

> Most objects contain all their properties in a single block of memory
>   ("a", and "b"). All blocks of memory have a pointer to a map, which
>   describes their structure. Named properties that don't fit in an
>   object are usually stored in an overflow array ("c", and "d").
>   Numbered properties are stored separately, usually in a contiguous
>   array.

For more read [here](http://jayconrod.com/posts/52/a-tour-of-v8-object-representation).

Comment: This article is five years old. I wonder if it's still up-to-date.

Comment: @torazaburo Yeah true. But I guess the underlying memory structure won't change much.

Answer (score 0):

The values of the class member variables of the object are stored in memory.  Those values, as a group, are associated with the block of code that is the class from which the object was created.   An object is simply data associated with a specific set of function calls designed to operate on it.

Consider a function based language like C.   You might do something like this.

```
struct Square (  
    int upperX;  
    int upperY;  
    int lowerX;  
    int lowerY;  
}
```

Clearly we are storing a square in memory here...

```
Square s = malloc (sizeof(Square) );  
s->upperX = 10;
s->upperY = 10;
s->lowerX = 20;
s->lowerY = 20;
```

Here is some code that operates on a Square... It takes a block of
memory that is the Square struct...
    function drawSquare( Square s) {.. code to draw}

Square is plainly stored in memory with its values.

Now, an object oriented language like C++ or Java plays tricks behind the scenes which does the same exact thing.  But the code looks more like this...

```
class Square {
    private int upperX;
    private int upperY;
    private int lowerX;
    private int lowerY;
    // Create and return an object
    public Square (int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {code to set members}
    // Draw a square
    public draw () {code to draw...}
}
```

And you make one like this....
    Square s = new Square(10,10,20,20);

Somewhere behind the scenes the malloc and assignments are done.  But s is an object in this case because the realized Square "struct" in memory is associated with the code in the Square class.